# how to grab some value from a 3rd party website and post it in my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to grab the value of Members: (this value) 
from this page: http://gamezconnect.com/en/group/gamezerexperts 
and post it in my website. Its a changing value thats why i want it to keep updatin automatically. Now, im changing it manually.

```
<li class='clear'>
<span class='value'>the value should be here</span> Room Players
</li>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will not write your code for you. As your question stands, it is too broad and lacks to many details to be answered well. Furthermore, we normally expect you to make an effort on your own before asking for help here. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/about for some guidelines on writing effective questions.

Comment: Maybe you could ask them to make a XML file or something that you can grab the data from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy answer, you can't.

This kind of problem is why websites that contain information used by other websites build APIs so that people can request particular data. In your case, I doubt that website has an API that you can use to grab that number.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will face Cross-domain issue here. If you would be getting value from same domain, then you can use `$('selector').load('url selectro > *')` to get some information from other page.

Comment: can you show me how to use that?

Comment: @user3489643 I have already included example of loading `selector` content to another `selector`. Left one is from local file, right one is from page within given url.

Answer (score -1):

```
<li class='clear'>
<span class='value'><?php
    $site = file_get_contents('http://gamezconnect.com/en/group/gamezerexperts');
    preg_match('~Members:[^0-9]<b>([0-9]+)</b>~', $site, $match);
    echo $match[1];
?></span> Room Players
</li>
```

Comment: http://temp.chobits.ch/room.php

Comment: OP, you need PHP to run it, which is why it's not such a great answer.

Comment: When someone says it's not possible but I make it possible, then what?

Comment: because it's tagged as javascript jquery html